# What font does the Phonly app uses?

Tags: font-identification

I would like to purchase the same font the [Windows Phone Phonly app](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/phonly/3bc60b34-c66f-4dc8-8fd0-dd497ba38711) uses. Anybody has idea what font is it?

[image]

Update: I tried font identification services such as [WhatTheFont](http://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/) and had no success.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The font is called [Cookie](http://www.1001fonts.com/cookie-font.html#styles) by Ania Kruk:

[image]

[image]

[image]
[Character Map](http://www.1001fonts.com/cookie-font.html#character-map)